# Demonstrating the difference between detached and not detached containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, detach

I have a very simple dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.14 AS build

LABEL version = "1.0"
LABEL description = "Our first Docker file!"
```

and a very simple docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.9"

# Define services
services:
    container1:
        container_name: first_container
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfile
```

I am running the docker-compose file with `docker-compose up` and, alternatively, `docker-compose up -d` to demonstrate that the container is still running in the detached configuration.

In the first case, I expect the container to run then close. It does. Running `docker-compose down` then stops and removes all the containers (first_container) as confirmed with `docker-compose ps`.

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "comdockerdevenvironmentscode_default" with the default driver
Creating first_container ... done
Attaching to first_container
first_container exited with code 0

$ docker-compose ps
     Name         Command   State    Ports
------------------------------------------
first_container   /bin/sh   Exit 0        

$ docker-compose down
Removing first_container ... done
Removing network comdockerdevenvironmentscode_default

$ docker-compose ps
Name   Command   State   Ports
------------------------------
```

Now, I rerun docker-compose up again, adding the detached command. Now, the output says it creates the container, but doesn't close it. Great! I should see a status change when running `docker-compose ps`, but it still seems to have exited.

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "comdockerdevenvironmentscode_default" with the default driver
Creating first_container ... done

$ docker-compose ps
     Name         Command   State    Ports
------------------------------------------
first_container   /bin/sh   Exit 0
```

Why is this? How can I show that I can attach to the running detached container, but not to the closed container in the other case?

Comment: A container is a wrapper around a single process; what's that process supposed to be?  (In the Dockerfile, what `CMD` should your image run?)

Comment: The only difference between the two runs is that you see 2 more messages when you're attached: `Attaching to first_container` and `first_container exited with code 0`. The container does the same in both runs. It starts and then it exits.

Comment: @HansKilian, okay, that makes sense. I expected the container to simply stay open. But I suppose if the container runs in the background (-d), it still *does* run in the background, but it also finishes its execution, so it closes. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @AaronJPung Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alpine` container, absent an explict configuration to the contrary, starts a shell (`/bin/sh`) by default. The shell exits immediately if `stdin` isn't open. Regardless of whether or not you run `docker-compose up` with `-d`, in all cases `stdin` is closed, so your container exits.

If you want the container to run a shell without exiting, then you need to arrange to *stdin* to remain connected. To get a prompt, you'll also need to have Docker allocate a tty. That means:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    container1:
        image: docker.io/alpine:latest
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
```

Running a container as in the above example means that you can `docker attach` to it and access the shell prompt.

Alternately, if you'd like the container to run without exiting, just run a command that won't exit:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    container1:
        image: docker.io/alpine:latest
        command: [sleep, inf]
```

This runs the `sleep inf` command, which runs until canceled. A more typical example would run some sort of persistent service like a web server, a database, etc.